# Complex nHibernate QueryOver expression

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have the following objects in a hierarchy `A > B > C > D`. Each object is mapped to a table.  I'm trying to write the following SQL using QueryOver:

```
SELECT B
FROM A, B, C, D
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
  AND B.ID = C.ID
  AND C.ID = D.ID
WHERE A.NUMBER = 'VALUE'
  AND D.NAME IN ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')
```

I have the C# code so far:

```
string[] entityNames = entityAttributes.Select(e => e.Name).ToArray();
string customerNumber = 2;

return session.QueryOver<B>()
              .JoinQueryOver(b => b.C)
              .JoinQueryOver(c => c.D)
              .WhereRestrictionOn(d => d.Name).IsIn(entityNames)
              .List<B>();
```

What's missing here is the `A > B` link.  I cannot figure out how to add the join to `A` restricting it on the `NUMBER` field.  I tried the following but the `.JoinQueryOver(b => b.C)` is looking for type `A` instead of finding type `B`.

```
return session.QueryOver<B>()
                .JoinQueryOver(b => b.A)
                    .Where(a => a.Number == customerNumber)
              .JoinQueryOver(b => b.C) **//Looks for type A instead of B**
              .JoinQueryOver(c => c.D)
              .WhereRestrictionOn(d => d.Name).IsIn(entityNames)
              .List<B>();
```

How can I add type `A` to this query while still returning type `B`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use Aliases to join your table like

```
B tB = null;
A tA = null;
C tC = null;
D tD = null;
var qOver = HibSession.QueryOver<B>(() => tB)
.JoinAlias(() => tB.A, () => tA, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.Where(() => tA.Number == customerNumber)
.JoinAlias(() => tB.C, () => tC, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.JoinAlias(() => tC.D, () => tD, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.Where(Restrictions.On(() => tD.Name).IsIn(entityNames))
.List<B>();
```

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you! This has worked like a charm in multiple scenarios of my application!