# could not resolve property (complex properties)

Tags: linq, nhibernate, queryover

I have a asp.net mvc application with NHibernate and I do not know how to resolve a problem to query some data. I have this query:

```
// create query
var query = session.QueryOVer<Laudo>().Fetch(x => x.Equipament).Eager;

// add some filters
if (idEquipament.HasValue) 
  query = query.And(x => x.Equipament.Id == idEquipament.Value);

//I got the error here...
if (idCompany.HasValue)
  query = query.And(x => x.Equipament.Company.Id == idCompany.Value);
```

When I try to execute this query, I've got an exception with this message:
"*could not resolve property: Equipament.Company.Id of: DomainModel.Laudo*"

what can I do to fix this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use another entity property like that. NHibernate expects expression that can be evaluated to property of the current entity. You need to use [`JoinQueryOver`](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-associations) or [`JoinAlias`](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-aliases) to join another entity, and perform `where` after that.

With `JoinQueryOver`:

```
// ...
query = query.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Equipment)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Company)
    .Where(c => c.Id == idCompany.Value);
```

With `JoinAlias`:

```
Equipment equipment = null;
Company company = null;

// ...
query = query.JoinAlias(x => x.Equipment, () => equipment)
    .JoinAlias(() => equipment.Company, () => company)
    .Where(() => company.Id == idCompany.Value);
```

Some more info:
[What is the difference between JoinQueryOver and JoinAlias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416560/what-is-the-difference-between-joinqueryover-and-joinalias)
[What can be used as a NHibernate QueryOver alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893733/what-can-be-used-as-a-nhibernate-queryover-alias)
[Complex nHibernate QueryOver expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519282/complex-nhibernate-queryover-expression)

Comment: just one question, is there any way to fill only some properties of this join, I mean... Company entity has more than 20 fields, and I need just 2 (Id and Name), is there any way to do that? Thanks

Comment: Projections? http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections

Answer (score 1):

The tags chosen for your question make me think you didn't want to use QueryOver, but LINQ.

This is achieved by using the extension method `Query`, in the `NHibernate.Linq` namespace:

```
var query = session.Query<Laudo>().Fetch(x => x.Equipament);
if (idEquipament.HasValue) 
  query = query.Where(x => x.Equipament.Id == idEquipament.Value);
if (idCompany.HasValue)
  query = query.Where(x => x.Equipament.Company.Id == idCompany.Value);
```

Comment: Hi @Diego, nice tip, but I used AND() method because It genarates an AND operator on the sql statment between the parameters (I have more parameters on my original method) something like `idEquipament = ? AND Equipament.Company_Id = ?` ... and using like you said, is there any advantage or it will be the same? Thank you!